# Using PHP script

Tags: php, android

I have a php script (with curl extension) and now I would like to create an Android app, that would use that script in the background. The app would have buttons and when a button would be pressed, the script would execute with values send by the buttons. Is that possible? If so, how (maybe a tutorial)?

Comment: do you want to execute it on a remote server or local on your device?

Comment: any reason you cant find/create a script in java that does what the php one does?  There aren't any clean solutions for running php locally on mobile.

Comment: How would I do `curl_setopt` in Android?

Answer (score 0):

> If so, how (maybe a tutorial)?

It appears to be possible .. Here is a [link.](http://phpforandroid.net/doku.php)

Also check this. [zend studio](http://yourstory.in/2012/10/now-php-developers-can-build-android-apps-using-zend-studio-10/)